# is it possible to store around 1 mb data in client machine using php or javascript or any other programing language?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

hi friends i am working on small test type module and i want facility like if may be client internet goes offline after test will be continuew without internet, is it possible using php or javascript or any programming language ?

same like offline test

Comment: PHP is a serverside language, and can't store things clientside, but Local Storage can, and all browsers that support it has at least 5 megabytes of storage.

Comment: hi adeneo i have data in my mysql database and i want store in client machine

Comment: what is best way for this like xml or excel to client machine without informing to client because questions are secret

Comment: maybe http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html ?

Comment: Yes by using webstorage over javascript. see http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option with the best support would be javascript local storage. It is supported by all browsers vs web SQL isn't. Cookies only allow 4kb so that won't be good. Local storage allows up to 5mb of storage. It is simple to store and retrieve items I will give you a link to a page that shows how or just google local storage. Another thing local storage is javascript. Another thing would be browser caching to store the actual page files and images in the browser cache. This option has its downfalls since the user can disable the cache and set how much data can be cached plus the cache data allowed is shared between all websites which means once the cache is gone you can't store anything. See this link: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html